# Included file generates error "value cannot be null"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In my application, i have some zip files:

[image]

[image]

It is present in the Resources.Designer.cs:

```
internal static byte[] ContactDocuments
    {
        get
        {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("ContactDocuments", resourceCulture);
            return ((byte[])(obj));
        }
    }
```

I have this code to extract the file tp c:\temp:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\ContactDocuments.zip", Properties.Resources.ContactDocuments);
```

The solution is build without any errors.

However, when I run the application, I get the error"value cannot be null" at the point the above code is executed.

I have been looking at the properties of the zip file, but i did not find a solution.

Comment: If you add a breakpoint on this line, what is the value of `Properties.Resources.ContactDocuments`?

Comment: What's the build action of the DontactDocuments.zip?

Comment: Right click on the project. Click Properties. Click Resources. Take a screenshot. Include that in your question. Also have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=netframework-4.7.2 .

Comment: What is the resourceCulture when you run this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mjwills was pointing in the right direction.
I had to "Right click on the project. Click Properties. Click Resources" and add the resource:

[image]

Now, i can access this resource when running the application.

Thanks